# Consistent approach for styling React components

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui, less

Just recently I have begun working with React, and to some extent front-end development. I am using the Material UI framework to develop an application, and I have chosen to use its "styling with JavaScript" approach: styles are defined as JavaScript objects, rather than traditional CSS, for example. All good so far.

I have my components in a `component` directory, and in a separate directory called `style` I have a matching file for each component where I define the `useStyle` hook (per component). That way, each component's style is defined via a unique import.

Now that I am integrating a non-Material UI third party library, the styling it ships with is defined with CSS, so I can just import the CSS file in my React component file to use the styling. But now I end up with a mixture of styling **techniques**.

Is there a single, consistent, and recommended approach for styling React applications? Is using multiple styling techniques recommended?

Comment: This is waaaaay too broad for Stack Overflow and will be closed in no time. But in general, the problem here isn't really "how do I style React apps?", the problem is you're importing multiple styles for a single element/component. This isn't anything to do with React or a specific framework, it's cos you're importing conflicting styling. In general, the "approach" is to use a CSS reset, and **one** styling theme for your site, The End. Mixing them will create issues that you can't easily resolve without a bunch of custom styling

Comment: @Jayce444 I don't consider the question too broad - I'm really just looking for recommendations for a consistent approach to unifying styling _techniques_. The problem I have is not conflicting styles, but different mechanisms of applying styles. I suspect this must be a very common problem, but I'm too new to web dev with React to discern a best practice. I'll refine the original question to make it more specific.